# Cant get FS button when loading youtube into flash, fs=1 does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-api

I am using flash to load a youtube video player with this code:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&autoplay=1&fs=1&modestbranding=1&controls=1"));
```

The player loads and all intended functionality is there except for the full screen button on the control bar. There is just a settings button where I would expect to be a fs button. I thought the fs=1 param in the url was supposed to make it work however, it is not. Is there another technique or something that I can change to make this work?

-This site seems to have a working example, you need to hover on the small unit for a moment then it will launch the larger unit that has a youtube player with the fs button.
http://www.richmediagallery.com/galleryDetail/?id=36055

Also its interesting to note that if I use the same exact url and load within HTML using Embed/Object, it will work with FS button??!?:(doesnt help me because I need this to work in flash)

```
<object width="640" height="390">
      <param name="movie"
             value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&autoplay=1&fs=1&modestbranding=1&controls=1"></param>
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
      <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&autoplay=1&fs=1&modestbranding=1&controls=1"
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
             allowscriptaccess="always"
             width="640" height="390"></embed>
    </object>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

youtube fullscreen button makes swf fullscreen not the player so you need to resize player to fullscreen
first off all add fullscreen eventListener to stage

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.FULLSCREEN, fullscreen);
```

then on event change make youtube player fullscreen or normal

```
private function fullscreen(e:Event):void
{
    if (stage.displayState != StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
    {
        matrix = (player as DisplayObject).transform.matrix;//store matrix
        player.setSize(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        player.x = player.y = 0;
        stage.addChild(player);
    }
    else
    {
        player.setSize(normalHeight, normalWidth);
        (player as DisplayObject).transform.matrix = matrix;//restore matrix
        loader.addChild(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ices_2 I think you misunderstood my question. I am looking on how to actually get that FS button to show on the nav bar. I dont have that button to click to make it FS. I did find a solution though it was complicated and had to work with a lib from DoubleClick for use of their YTPlayerProxy. I got it working though it was painful. I dont get why normal youtube documented information does not work, or im trying to figure out if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution however, it was painful to implement.

After alot of guessing/researching the fix was to use DoubleClickStudio lib(google ads) and they have a component lib called YTPlayerProxy.

If you use those together, you can get the FS button to appear.

The biggest challenge was getting this to work within an ide like ftd because those libs were components within Flash Professional. So when coding in an IDE, your ide does not know about that code base and will throw errors everywhere.

To fix that I had to find where the component installed, then grab the swc asset though that was for YTPlayer.

For DoubleClick(I actually had a .fla with double click lib inside that was passed to me. I could not find a place to download from web though I didnt search super hard), I had to convert my .fla to a .zip then find the .swc that was holding double click info.

Once I got both .swc's I loaded them into FDT and everything was good.